# plotly mapbox - create clusters in mapview

Tags: mapbox, geospatial, plotly-dash, mapbox-gl-js

I am building Dash App that uses plotly [`scattermapbox` graph object](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Scattermapbox.html). In the current map view each point is represented as a circle. As a user zooms-in and out, I'd like to cluster the points and create groupings. Here's my code for reference.

```
import dash
from dash import dcc
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
                   'x': [1, 2, 3],
                   'Lat': [37.774322, 37.777035, 37.773033],
                   'Long': [-122.489761, -122.485555, -122.491220]
                 }) 

layout = html.Div(
                   dcc.Graph(id="map"),
                   dcc.Input(id="inp")
                 )

@app.callback(
              Output('map','figure'),
              Input('inp','value')
             )
def fin(val):
    
    # do something

    data = []
    
    data.append({

                                 "type": "scattermapbox",
                                 "lat": df["Lat"],
                                 "lon": df["Long"],
                                 "name": "Location",
                                 "showlegend": False,
                                 "hoverinfo": "text",
                                 "mode": "markers",
                                 "clickmode": "event+select",
                                 "customdata": df.loc[:,cd_cols].values,
                                 "marker": {
                                            "symbol": "circle",
                                            "size": 8,
                                            "opacity": 0.7,
                                            "color": "black"
                                           }
                                 }
                   )

      layout = {

                     "autosize": True,
                     "hovermode": "closest",
                     "mapbox": {

                         "accesstoken": MAPBOX_KEY,
                         "bearing": 0,
                         "center": {
                             "lat": xxx,
                             "lon": xxx
                         },
                         "pitch": 0,
                         "zoom": zoom,
                         "style": "satellite-streets",

                     },

                    
        }

        return ({'data': data, 'layout': layout})
```

Answer (score 0):

try using `plotly.graph_objects.scattermapbox.Cluster`. Hope this helps:

```
from dash import dcc, html, Dash, Output, Input
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go


app = Dash(__name__)

df = pd.DataFrame({
                   'x': [1, 2, 3],
                   'Lat': [37.774322, 37.777035, 37.773033],
                   'Long': [-122.489761, -122.485555, -122.491220]
                 }) 


@app.callback(
              Output('map','figure'),
              Input('inp','value')
             )
def fin(val):
    data = []
    
    data.append({
                    "type": "scattermapbox",
                    "lat": df["Lat"],
                    "lon": df["Long"],
                    "name": "Location",
                    "showlegend": False,
                    "hoverinfo": "text",
                    "mode": "markers",
                    "clickmode": "event+select",
                    "customdata": df.loc[:,['Lat', 'Long']].values,
                    "marker": {
                            "symbol": "circle",
                            "size": 8,
                            "opacity": 0.7,
                            "color": "black"
                            },
                    "cluster": {'maxzoom': 14}
                    }
    )

    layout = {
                    "autosize": True,
                    "hovermode": "closest",
                    "mapbox": {
                        "bearing": 0,
                        "center": {
                            "lat": 37.774322,
                            "lon": -122.489761
                        },
                        "pitch": 0,
                        "zoom": 7,
                        "style": "open-street-map",
                    },
    }

    return ({'data': data, 'layout': layout}) 


app.layout = html.Div(
                   [dcc.Graph(id="map"),
                    dcc.Input(id="inp")]
                 )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Notice the added `cluster` parameters I added to `data`.

p.s - make sure you are using a new version of dash for this to work. I used the latest version - `dash-2.7.1`.